# Is it possible to have condition in mongoose populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a sub document called *services* in a collection it contains *serviceID* and *type*. *serviceID* is referred to two collections *internalservice* and *externalservice* varies based on the type field.

```
internalServices:[{
           serviceID:ObjectId('0000000000000'),
           serviceDesc:'sweeping'
         },
         {
           serviceID:ObjectId('0000000000000'),
           serviceDesc:'floor cleaning'
         }]


 externalServices:[{
               serviceID:ObjectId('0000000000000'),
               serviceDesc:'painting'
             },
             {
               serviceID:ObjectId('0000000000000'),
               serviceDesc:'white washing'
             }]
```

Above two are lookup collection. And here the company collection

```
   _id:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   name: 'xxxx',
   Address:'xxx',

    services:[{
           serviceID:ObjectId('0000000000000'),
           type: internalservice
         },
         {
           serviceID:ObjectId('0000000000000'),
           type: externalservice
         }]
```

Here, i want to populate service description based on type.

Is it possible to have conditional path at populate?

Here's my code

```
Company.findOne({"_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.companyID)},
                {})
             .populate('services.serviceID','serviceDesc','InternalService')
             .exec(function (err, companyInfo) {

               console.log(companyInfo);
             });
```

**This populates internal service description but i need to populate external service description for type externalservice**. When i have two populate the second populate replaces the result with null for unmatched documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can include in populate `where` conditions like:

```
Story
.find(...)
.populate({
  path: 'fans',
  match: { age: { $gte: 21 }},
  select: 'name -_id',
  options: { limit: 5 }
})
.exec()
```

[Here is the Mongoose Populate Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)