# Mongoose GroupBy with Populate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have User document and and Category document which is connected to shop document which look like

```
  var ShopSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    shopName: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'A Shop must have name'],
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        validate: [validator.isMobilePhone,"Phone number is not a valid number"],
        required: [true, 'A Shop must have hepline number'],
    },
    shopStatus: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
        select: false
    },
    managerId:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref:'User',
        require: [true,'Shop must have to a manager!']
    },
    createdAt:{
        type:Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    shopCategory:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref:'Category',
        require: [true,'Shop must have a Category!']
    },

  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
  }
);

const Shop = mongoose.model("Shop", ShopSchema);
```

Now i am writing a query to get managers shop(groupBy managerId) with populate of Manager and Category data. but i am getting empty array everytime.

```
 const doc = await Shop.aggregate([
        { 
            $match: { shopStatus: {$ne: false} } 
        },
        { 
            $group: {
                _id:'$managerId',
                numofShop: {$sum: 1},
                shopCategory: {$first: "$shopCategory"}
            }
        },
        { 
            $lookup: {
               from: "User",
               localField : "_id",
               foreignField: "_id",
               as: "Manager"
             }
       },
       { 
            $lookup: {
                from: "Category",
                localField : "shopCategory",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "Category"
            }
       },
     ])
```

here is how my final result look like but this is an empty array.

```
        {
            "_id": "5f467660f630e804ec07fad8",
            "numofShop": 2,
            "Manager": [],
            "Category": []
        },
        {
            "_id": "5f44d2f4ff04993b40684bf9",
            "numofShop": 1,
            "Manager": [],
            "Category": []
        }
```

I want to find All shops groupBy managerId(Who own it). there is field of managerId referencing to User document who created this shop. i want data like this

```
    {
        "_id": "5f44d2f4ff04993b40684bf9",
        "Manager": {},//this is populated through User Schema
        "numofShop": 1,
        "Shop": [
                  { 
                     "shopName":"Grocery Shop",
                     "phone" : "111111",
                     "shopCategory" :{"_id": "","name":"Electronics"}
                  }
                ]
    }
    .....
    .....
```

Find Example Data here
Shops- http://txt.do/1fwi0
3 shops created by two users
User - http://txt.do/1fwio
Categories- http://txt.do/1fwij

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 fixes,

- in second lookup you have no `shopCategory` field in localField because you have not defined `shopCategory` in `$group`,

```
{ 
  $group: {
    _id:'$managerId',
    numofShop: {$sum: 1},
    shopCategory: { $first: "$shopCategory" } // define here
  }
},
```

- in first lookup with user collection, there is no `managerId` field and you have assigned in `_id` field, then you can use `_id` in localField,

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "User",
    localField : "_id", // change this from managerId
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "Manager"
  }
},
```

Updated things after updated question, [Playground1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3LNtguwgUNU), [Playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z1GkuL5X--z)

---

for your second edit, you can't put condition for populate in find method, how to put condition in populate, you can follow the [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37003217/8987128) and [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40339260/is-it-possible-to-have-condition-in-mongoose-populate)

Comment: Thanks.i have another query i have User doc which have roles an array of object ids. i am writing this query. i want all users with roles in inventory,delivery,account.         const doc = await User.find({
       "roles.name": {$in :["Inventory Manager","Delivery Manager","Account Manager"]}
     }).populate("roles");

Comment: this is return empty array

Comment: i can't predict without seeing your schemas.

Comment: can you confirm this data and query its correct or not https://mongoplayground.net/p/laQGSunXwWF , or please provide data for all collection

Comment: Please Check example data i also provide my desired result that i want.

Comment: where is the manager ids? i think you need to explain your question properly, you have changed many things, sorry i can't help you someone will help you.

Comment: In shop document there is field call managerId which pointing to User document. there are many shops created by many users. i want shops of each user so that i can show shops of each user.

Comment: hope you give one more try

Comment: can you confirm [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3LNtguwgUNU) now. and second way if you like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z1GkuL5X--z)